# Dimensional Modeling: How do I handle a hierarchy in a factless fact table?

Tags: dimensional-modeling

I'm kind of new to dimensional modeling. It seems to me that a lot of my data do not have specific measures.  For instance, we have Organizations, and each has 1 or more Locations.  There are attributes at the Organization and at the Location level that we need to filter/slice by.  The only real measurement we care about is the count of Organizations and Locations, e.g., how many Organizations exist in a certain zip code.

1. Do I create one fact table where each Location shows up once, and
   Organizations show up 1 or more times?  Then I have to deal with
   duplicate Organizations.
2. Do I create two fact tables?  If I do, do I create a bridge table between them?

I'm leaning towards #2.  Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

If you have facts at the location level of granularity then you would normally create a Location dimension that included the parent Org and its attributes (i.e. you denormalise the Org into the Location). You might also have a separate Org dimension if you have facts at the Org level as well.

If you can answer a query by just using a dimension table then there is no requirement to build a fact table e.g. if you want to know how many Locations per Org you have then just query the Location dimension table.

Obviously if, for example, you are using a BI tool that requires a fact table then you may need to create one in your DWH if your BI tool cannot construct a "virtual" fact table from the Dimension

Comment: Thank you.  I should have mentioned I have additional dimensions to hang off of each Location and Org, like Location Specialties Available and Organization Languages Spoken.  Given that I'm leaning even more towards 2 fact tables since there will be different dimensions for each.